# Inductor held with hands

Tags: resistors, switches, inductor, voltage-source

I have a fairly simple problem, but as I am a newbie in electrical circuits I was hoping someone might help me understand the principles of things.

[image]

I have a circuit with an inductor of L = 0,102H a resistor of 20k ohms and a voltage source of 10V. The question is how much current will 'accumulate' (if thats even how it works) and if I were to disconnect S1 (or flip it so that that the voltage source would no longer apply) what would happen to the body (represented as a resistor).. How much voltage there would be and how much current would run through it. Also in what manner would the current run?

Comment: Is that a practical circuit ? Or just theoretical ?
Because in theory with the switch closed the current though the inductor will approach infinity.

In a practical circuit the power supply would have some output impedance and the inductor has ESR.

The inductor's voltage is given by: V = L*di/dt .

As you flip the switch you are trying to stop the current very very quickly, thus di/dt is very very high and so is the voltage.

Comment: Solely theoretical.. So the current truly grows as a line? So is it possible that in just a few seconds the current on the inductor will be hundreds of A? Also theoretically if I open the S1, how fast is the current 'consumed' (reach 0) and what happens to the resistor? (my thought was that it would burn out as there are megavolts and almost kiloampers going through it)    Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: This could be a practical circuit... a defibrillator.

Comment: A defibrilator has low current though, right? Becuase from what I understand even 50V can kill you if there is enough current..?

Comment: it is the current that kills, just need the voltage to make it run. 30mA running through you heart will already make the kill. So with a couple of needles pinched to the chest you will not even make it to the 50V.  

But for the circuit, in theory the current would be infinite in a infinite small amount of time, in practice the inductor will be smoking in a very small amount of time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the switch, current through the inductor will build up linearly at a rate of di = V*dt/L = 98A per second.

When you open the switch the final current will initially keep flowing (in the same direction) through the inductor. Since the switch is open the only possible path is now through the body. If the body's resistance was 20kΩ and you opened the switch after 1 second, then the current would reach 98A and voltage would spike to 98A*20kΩ = 1.96MV.

Since the current is flowing in the same direction through the inductor it must go in reverse through the body (ie. upwards in your diagram) compared to the current that was flowing through it when the switch was closed.

As the magnetic energy in the inductor is drained out the current (and voltage) will decay exponentially with a time constant of L/R, so the body will only receive that 98A at 1.96MV for a short time. As to what would happen to it, how should I know? - I'm an engineer not a doctor!